# Passing variables from the external function to the callback function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm a bit confused about using callback functions in `JavaScript`, when doing the following call for example:

```
func(obj , callback);
```

and let's assume that `func` sends some `AJAX` request , and gets an object as a response,let's call it `resObj`, do I need to pass it to the callback if I want to use it there? Thank You

Comment: it should be `callback` not `callback()`, and yes, then you can do `callback(resObj)` or you can use `callback` as success callback directly, or the resolve receiver of promise directly like `.then(callback)`

Comment: if you wanna use you have to pass. Also you can think of using promises.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee fixed that ,thank you ..

Comment: if you have Async request inside function use promises, it is best practice.

Comment: yes actually the request is asynchronous

Comment: Thank you every one ,I'll check the promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when doing a `func(obj, callback);` call for example, do I need to pass the result to the callback if I want to use it there?

No, you don't. `func` will pass the result into callback when calling it back, that's the whole point. You only need to accept it as a parameter when writing the `callback` function.

```
function func(o, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() { // or ajax request or whatever
        const resObj = o.example + 3;
        cb(resObj); // here the result is passed to the callback
    }, 50);
}
```

```
function callback(resObj) {
    console.log(resObj);
}
const obj = {example: 38};
func(obj, callback); // You're not *calling* the callback here
```